# Count positive and negative words in a string considering negatives and negation

Tags: r, regex, string

The following code matches positive and negative words in a text and counts them. Let us consider e.g.

```
sentences<-c("You are not perfect!", 
            "However, let us not forget what happened across the Atlantic.", 
            "And I can't support you.",
            "No abnormal energy readings",
            "So with gratitude, the universe is abundant forever.")
```

We first import positive and negative words

```
pos = readLines("positive-words.txt")
neg = readLines("negative-words.txt")
```

from txt files. In these files we found:

```
abundant
gratitude
perfect
support
```

for `positive-words.txt` and

```
abnormal
```

for `negative-words.txt`. The following commands:

```
sentence = gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", sentence)
sentence = gsub("[[:cntrl:]]", "", sentence)
sentence = gsub('\\d+', '', sentence)
```

remove digits, control characters and punctuations. Then we split sentence into words with `str_split (stringr package)`

```
word.list = str_split(sentence, "\\s+")
words = unlist(word.list)
```

and compare words to the dictionaries of positive & negative terms

```
pos.matches = match(words, pos)
neg.matches = match(words, neg)
pos.matches = !is.na(pos.matches)
neg.matches = !is.na(neg.matches)
```

The variable `sentence` can be `sentences[1]`, `sentences[2]`, `sentences[3]`, `sentences[4]` or `sentences[5]`. E.g. if `sentence=sentences[5]`, this code correctly returns two positive words; in fact the result is:

```
> pos.matches
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

The same happens for all the other sentences. E.g. if `sentence=sentences[4]`:

```
> neg.matches
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Anyway, I would like to modify this code in order to address the situations enclosed in `sentences[1]`, `sentences[3]` and `sentences[4]`. In fact: `perfect` in `sentences[1]` is a positive word but it is preceded by `not` and then I would like to consider these two words as one (negative) term; `support` in `sentences[3]` is a positive word but it is preceded by `cant` and then I would like to consider these two words as a negative term; `abnormal` in `sentences[4]` is a negative word but it is preceded by `no` and then I would like to consider these two words as one positive term. E.g. the desired result for `sentence=sentences[4]` is:

```
> pos.matches
[1] TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Instead, with this code I obtain:

```
> pos.matches
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

I thought then define a variable with negatives and negations:

```
NegativesNegations <- paste("\\b(", paste(c("no","not","couldnt","cant"), collapse = "|"), ")\\b")
```

But I don't know how to move forward with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this task with plain regex.
First you transform your positive and negative lists into regex strings as you did with the list of negative negations:

```
pos_rgx = paste0("\\b(", paste(pos, collapse="|"), ")\\b")
neg_rgx = paste0("\\b(", paste(neg, collapse="|"), ")\\b")
```

you can now check for every sentence if a positive or negative word exists:

```
grepl(pos_rgx, sentences, ignore.case=TRUE)
grepl(neg_rgx, sentences, ignore.case=TRUE)
```

for adding the negations you can proceed accordingly:

```
pos_neg_rgx = paste0('\\b(no|not|couldn\'t|can\'t)\\s', pos_rgx)
grepl(pos_neg_rgx, sentences)
```

note: '\\s' means that a single whitespace is between the negation and the positive word

note(2): if you quote your string with single-quotes, then you have to escape the the quote in "can't" (like in the example). Otherwise you can quote the string using double-quotes: "\b(no|not|couldn't|can't)\s"

If you like to dig deepet into text-mining, have a look at package [tidytext](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidytext)